# EJS content is not loading after redirect to page

Tags: ajax, ejs

I've got page, where part of content is loading dynamically with EJS. 
Data to EJS is retrieved from AJAX request. 
When I open the page for the first time it's working fine. But I need function, which reload page and add to link some variables after ?. 
After calling this function, my EJS content isn't loading. Any ideas why?

Calling function from EJS:

```
<div class="img-cont"><img onclick="edit('<%= cl.ID %>')"></div>
```

JS function:

```
function edit(id){
window.location.href="url.html?id="id";
}
```

in HTML:

```
 var rq1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
      rq1.open("POST", url, false);
      rq1.send('action=my'); 
      var ml =  rq1.responseText;
      ml = $.parseJSON(ml);

 var rq1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
      rq1.open("POST", url, false);
      rq1.send('action=cl'); 
      var cl =  rq1.responseText;
      cl = $.parseJSON(cl);


  (function () {
     var html = new EJS({url: "xxx.ejs"}).render(ml, cl);
     document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = html;
   }());
```